# Passing Variables to a Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I've searched the other "variable to modal" threads and I can't quite find the answer I need. I have an ASP.NET application (non-MVC) and I have a grid that generates a series of buttons. I'm trying to keep my modal operations on the client side. My resulting button code looks like the following:

```
    <input type="button" value="Add Note" 
    onclick="return false;javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grd888Poker&#39;,&#39;Button$4001&#39;)" 
class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" 
data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#myModal" 
entryID="4001" />
```

The modal pops up just fine. But I need to pass the attribute entryID to a hidden field in the modal. Obv I need some sort of JS but since I'm letting Bootstrap handle the modal code there isn't anything for me to override. How can I pass the variable to the modal in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always attach an event to the modal to when it is shown, and either append a hidden input field or set the value of an already existing hidden input field. The `show.bs.modal` event should be invoked every time the modal is shown, even if Bootstrap handles the modal showing or if you're showing it from JavaScript.

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    $("#entryField").val($('#myModal').attr("entryID"));
})
```

or

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    var hiddenField = $(document.createElement("input")).prop("type", "hidden").appendTo("#myModal"); 
})
```

Button events:

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function() {
    $("#myModal").find("input[type='hidden']").val($(this).attr("entryID"); 
});
```

Mind you, this requires the hidden field to already exist inside the modal window.

Comment: thank you, this is on the right track. But keep in mind that I have many buttons with the same code. I see how your code sets the variable, but how do I set it to the *specific* variable from the button that was pressed (all buttons open the same modal).

Comment: That you have to do with a custom event on all the buttons. They can easily set the value of the hidden field in the modal, since it is a static element. But you can't see which button was invoked to open up the modal. Updating answer to include the button events.